# Word for acting in such a way that it intentionally expresses a personality

Tags: single-word-requests

In particular, I want a word that describes someone who dresses in order to express their personality .

Social-singnaling would be an example of this; subcultures dress in distinctive ways, such as punks sporting mohawks, goths heavy makeup, etc, which affirms both personal aesthetic preference as well as their solidarity with those dressed similarly.

The sentence is :

> Women possess far greater agency, which they exercise by dressing [expressively?]

Comment: Could use _distinctively_.

Comment: while ***suggestively*** typically applies to sexual suggestions, in theory any style of dress as you describe above is *suggesting* something about their preferences.

Comment: As long as filling a word in the last spot of your sentence is concerned, one can use *accordingly*. I don't know of a word specific to fashion. I'll look into it though.

Comment: If you want to indicate they are dressing to identify with a particular subculture, you could say they are dressing *tribally*

Answer (score 1):

See [accentuate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accentuate) and [foreground](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foreground) defined by Merriam Webster.

> To make something more prominent or noticeable. 
>   To give emphasis on a particular feature.

A few examples follow.

*A dress that accentuates her abs.*
*A robe that foregrounds his shoulders.*
*She togged herself up in accentuating clothes.*